# Euclidean Metric on $\mathbb{R}$ - Section 1.2 Micheal Searcoid

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Self studying the book Metric Spaces by Searcoid. Not able to understand the following sentence :

> A metric on a set $X$ is defined on $X\times X$, not on $X$. Nonetheless, some metrics, such as the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$, are determined by a function that is defined on $X$ itself.

What does it mean that the Euclidean metric is not defined on $X\times X$ but on $X\text{ ?}$
Don't we require $2$ points in $\mathbb R$ to define the metric?

On an earlier page he indicated that the Euclidean space is defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ :

> The most familiar example is that determined by the absolute-value function on $\mathbb{R}$; it is the function $(a,b)\mapsto |a-b|$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. This metric is called the *Euclidean metric* on $ \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I dont't think that what the author wrote is helpful. I can only guess that he considers the metric as the composition of a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $x\mapsto |x|$ with the function $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$

Comment: It says it's defined on $X\times X,$ not on $X. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Apologies for not being clear

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ and define
$$
d_\varphi(x,y)=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|
$$
Such a function $d_\varphi$ is a metric on $X$ so long as $\varphi$ is injective. Indeed $d_\varphi(x,y)\ge0$ is obvious; if $d_\varphi(x,y)=0$, then $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$ and, by injectivity we conclude $x=y$.

The property $d_\varphi(y,x)=d_\varphi(x,y)$ is obvious. The triangular inequality follows from
$$
d_\varphi(x,z)=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)+\varphi(y)-\varphi(z)|
\le|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|+|\varphi(y)-\varphi(z)|=
d_\varphi(x,y)+d_\varphi(y,z)
$$

Not all metrics can be defined this way. For instance the discrete metric can't.

---

However, the author is possibly referring to *normed spaces*: if $V$ is a normed space, we can deduce a metric by setting $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

The structure of normed space can also be weakened: what's actually needed is a group (usually written additively) $G$ together with a function $\nu\colon G\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

1. $\nu(x)\ge0$, for every $x\in G$;
2. $\nu(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$;
3. $\nu(x+y)\le\nu(x)+\nu(y)$.

Then $(x,y)\mapsto\nu(x-y)$ defines a metric on $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Referring to your answer, my question is should it not be : Consider a function φ:XxX→R (in the first line)
and NOT : Consider a function φ:X→R
The metric is defined on XxX
The author is highlighting that distinction for Euclidean metric, which I am not able to understand.
He discusses metrics on normed spaces in a later section.

Comment: @sidharth The idea is that from the function $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ we can define a metric $d_\varphi\colon X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$.